# imported python module from another directory fails

Tags: python, python-import, pythonpath

I have imported a python module from another directory in Linux by using `sys.path.insert` but when I run that module it fails. As the imported module is trying to open a file that is local to that module. Please let me know how to fix this.

```
users/adr/release/invoke.py  #this one fails with can’t open file ./config.ini

import sys

sys.path.insert(0, ‘/user/cdw/audit/’)

import audit_main
```

The path where the original module file resides.

```
/user/cdw/audit/audit_main.py  # this module opens config.ini file to read pplication credentials.
/user/cdw/audit/config.ini

/user/cdw/audit/__ini__.py
```

Comment: You may be able to use that module's `__file__` variable. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "config.ini")`

Comment: When asking these types of questions, it's a lot nicer/better if you add a folder structure like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62102453/how-to-define-callbacks-in-separate-files-plotly-dash/62102585#621025859), and add a full stack trace of your error in a code block. Makes our job a LOT easier.

Comment: @drum You messed up the indentation on that edit.

Comment: @tdelaney, it is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When python loads a module it adds metadata to its global namespace that can be used by the module. `__file__` is the filename of its .py file - when such a name makes sense. You can use it to get your config file

```
import os
config_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "config.ini")
```

except for when you can't. If this is a C extension file or if the file was in some other packaging like zip or egg or pyinstaller bundle or exe, it may not work. A ini file, which I assume is user editable, may need to be some place other than the module directory. If you make this .py part of an installable package, it may end up in a system directory the user can't edit. This may not be a problem for this project, just laying out some of the considerations.

Comment: Have a look at [pkguti.get_data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data). It can dig data out of zips/eggs as well as the filesystem. It doesn't handle namespace packages, though.