# Plotly Dash callback dependent on another callback not being triggered

Tags: python, callback, tabs, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am using Plotly Dash to create a dashboard. I want to have multiple tabs, and when the user clicks on any particular tab, for relevant callbacks to be triggered.

The `main.py` file calls a `layout.py` file to generate the layout. Here is a code snippet of how I'm going about it.

```
def create_layout(app):
    
    @callback(Output("tab-output", "children"), Input("tab-input", "value"))
    def update_tab(tab):
        if tab == "tabname1":
            return my_individual_script.render(app)  # might work, might not
        elif tab == "tabname2":
            return f"You selected tab {tab}."  # works properly
    
    # 1st alternative (succeeds ✅)
    layout = html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Tabs(id="tabs-input", value="tabname1",
                 children=[dcc.Tab(label="foo", value="tabname1"), dcc.Tab(label="bar", value="tabname2")]),
        my_individual_script.render(app)
    ])
    
    # 2nd alternative (fails ❌)
    layout = html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Tabs(id="tab-input", value="tabname1",
                 children=[dcc.Tab(label="foo", value="tabname1"), dcc.Tab(label="bar", value="tabname2")]),
        html.Div(id="tab-output")
    ])
    return layout
```

What I expect / what I have tried:

1. I want `update_tab` to call the right separate scripts to render all the content for that tab. Hence the use of `my_individual_script`.
2. The 1st alternative which succeeds 'statically' calls the render function from `my_individual_script` with its own callback.
3. The 2nd alternative which fails only calls `my_individual_script` IF the tab name is correct. Obviously, this is the desired behavior because I want content to change based on the tab selection. Here, I place an `html.Div` with the ID `tab-output` to trigger `update_tab`. I think it should work because I get the expected behavior from `tabname2`.
4. I have tried supplying `Input("tab-output", "children")` to `my_individual_script`'s callback based on my tenuous understanding of chained callbacks, but I'm not sure if that's applicable here, considering that the callback is triggered based on `if` conditions in the parent callback. It also doesn't work.

Here is code in `my_individual_script.py` with its callback that fails to trigger in the 2nd alternative:

```
def render(app):
    @callback(Output("output-div", "children"), [Input("dropdown", "value")])
    def update_value(value):
        return f"You have selected {value}."

    div = html.Div(children=[
        dcc.Dropdown(["foo", "bar"], "foo", id="dropdown"),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(id="output-div")
    ])
    return div
```

In this code, a dropdown menu with two options is initialized and all I want to do is print out what the user has selected in an `html.Div` below the dropdown. This is ultimately the `div` I want to show up when I write `html.Div(id="tab-output")` in the 2nd alternative.

The problem is that the callback in `my_individual_script` just isn't triggered. Why is that the case SPECIFICALLY when I try access its content through an `html.Div` with the parent callback's output ID?

Is it to do with my callback being dependent on another callback, so `dash` doesn't see it when it's initialized?

How can I allow for 'dynamic' loading of scripts based on the tab the user has clicked?

---

Apologies for any possible syntax errors here. I've had to transcribe this code from another computer, so any errors here do not correspond to syntax errors in the code I'm working with.

I am not getting any error messages so it's difficult to search for answers on StackOverFlow or elsewhere that correspond to my issue.

Comment: I think defining a callback in the create_layout() function is problematic, why don't you put the callback definition in main.py ? Same for the render function, why do you register a callback on render, why not once in main.py or in a dedicated file callbacks.py ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment; I think it's solved my problem. As to your question, I primarily followed ArjanCodes' video guide for dash (see [here](https://youtu.be/GlRauKqI08Y?t=549)) as this was one of the first larger projects I was designing from the ground up. As for your separate callbacks.py suggestion, I followed it according to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196559/12079010) and it worked like a charm (just in case anyone in the future has this problem)